# multiple select save based on checkboxs selected

Tags: php

I currently have multiple checkboxes and selects , when a checkbox is not checked the select box next to the checkbox is disabled, when checked it is enabled, the question how would i save the drop down values based on the checkbox selected. i know you can use a foreach loop in php to get a array of the selected checkboxs, how would i match it with the number of selected checkboxs.

```
<form id="form" name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"> 
    <?php  
        for($i=0; $i<=10; ++$i){
        ?>
        <input type="checkbox" class="status" name="status[]" value="1" id="status_enable_<?php echo $i; ?>" />
        <select id="reason_codes_<?php echo $i; ?>" name="reason_codes_<?php echo $i; ?>">
            <option value="">--none--</option>
            <option value="AB">--option1--</option>
            <option value="CD">--option2--</option>
            <option value="EF">--option3--</option>
            <option value="GH">--option4--</option>
        </select></br>
        <?
        }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" value="save" name="action" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use [jQuery](http://jquery.com) to check whether then checkbox is enabled and than send the data with the $.post Methode

Comment: And how do you do that? This isn't a great answer.